# The two child iframe pages that I embed into the parent html page are not being displayed

Tags: html, jenkins

This is my first post on stack overflow. I hope you could bear with me if I accidentally unintentionally am not following a few insiders' rules on this first post of mine.

**Background:**
Our team's Jenkins tool helps generate two html pages/files, which are basically my team's hardware simulation test reports. I put together a simple parent html page/file(It's called overview.html) in order to combine the two report page into one page. This overview.html has two iframes in it, and each iframe contains a src="..." link to the two afore-mentioned generated html pages. My teammates hope to be able to use this one page to view those generated pages at once in one place.

This setup used to work. But recently, when we open that overview.html, the iframes are not being displayed. Instead, it displays these error messages in each of those two iframes:

**HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found**

**URI**:    /static-files/Session_20Data_20for_20Overview_20Report/index.html

**STATUS**: 404

**MESSAGE**:    Not Found

**SERVLET**:    Stapler

Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.46.v20220331

**What I've tried:**

1. My go-to browser is google Chrome. I tried using firefox, the issue stays.
2. Things seem to work in our Team's Linux environment, but it's not working for our go-to windows environment.
3. I've checked the src="" links in each of those two iframes, the paths are correct. Let me list the file structure below:

--top directory

----Overview

------overview.html

----Session_20Data_20for_20Overview_20Report

------index.html

----Runs_20Data_20for_20Overview_20Report

------index.html

**Other helpful information:**

1. My overview.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>   
  <head>
    <title>regression report</title>   
  </head>   
  <body>
    <iframe
      style="width: 100%; height: 300px"
      src="**../Session_20Data_20for_20Overview_20Report/index.html**"
    ></iframe>
    <iframe
      style="width: 100%; height: 1000px"
      src="**../Runs_20Data_20for_20Overview_20Report/index.html**"
    ></iframe>   
  </body> 
</html>
```

2. I also see this warning in that "Runs Report" page, not sure if this has anything to do with this issue:
   Due to Cross Origin Request Security(CORS), this browsing mode is now deprecated. Use Detachable Report Mode instead.

That's pretty much it. Please feel free to let me know if you've run into something like this. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Fair enough. Don't forget to accept your answer after the 2-day lockout. Please delete the comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: Using the fully qualified URL solved my problem!
(Although I still don't know why using relative paths were not working for me..)